# Query using Oracle Parameter returns no result 11g

Tags: c#, oracle11g

A simple select statement using variable binding gives no rows??

```
  OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
  con.Open();
 OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
  cmd.Connection = con;
  cmd.CommandText = "select country_name from hr.countries where country_id = :country_id;

  OracleParameter p_country_id = new OracleParameter();
  p_country_id.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;

  p_country_id.Value = "UK";

  cmd.Parameters.Add(p_country_id);

  OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

  if (dr.Read())
  {} ---> no rows
```

tried adding parameterName ,direction,size still result is 0???

Any help??

Comment: Are you sure that there is a country in the table that has UK id? Have you tried using LIKE? You must add parameter name if you want to use it in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for responding guys, My unit test project app.config was pointing to wrong DB schema :(

Grrrrrrrrrrrrr! can't get anything stupid then this :) i will blame on my flu :)

Comment: You still want to make sure to wrap your SQL within `using` statement or you will leave SQL connections open when exceptions occur.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is all correct but it is written in NotePad.  At the very least it should get you on the right track.

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr))
{
    con.Open();
    using (OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select country_name from hr.countries where country_id = :country_id";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("country_id", "UK")

        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read()) 
       { 
            // You code here
       }
    }
}
```

NOTE:  I put the `using` statements in there because this is always recommended when executing database queries.  If an exception occurs the using statement will guarantee your database connection is still closed.

Comment: where is the " ending within select statement?

Comment: @Gauls I did not notice that.  I just copied the code from your question and you are missing that as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to give your parameter a name. Do so and it should work:

```
p_country_id.ParameterName = "country_id";
```